# Typescript length of a generic type

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

I have a function that looks like

```
export function is<T extends any[]>(...klasses): Predictor<T> {
    return (...variables: T) => {
        return variables
            .every((variable, index) => variable instanceof klasses[index]);
    }
}
```

In this example, I want to make sure `klasses` is of the same length as the array that `T` is. How do make `klasses` of type `any[]` with the same length as `T`?

**Update**

Based on the comments, I've updated this to

```
export function is<T extends Array<any>>(...klasses: any[] & {length: T['length']}): Predictor<T> {
    return (...variables: T) => {
        return variables
            .every((variable, index) => variable instanceof klasses[index]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the length of the classes array, then restrict variables length to be the same:

```
export function is<TClasses extends any[]>(...klasses: TClasses) {
    return (...variables: any[] & { length: TClasses['length'] }) => {
        return variables
            .every((variable, index) => variable instanceof klasses[index]);
    }
}

is(Number, String)(1, 1); // ok
is(Number, String)(1); // error: Types of property 'length' are incompatible
```

But in this case you won't be able to specify variables type upfront. If you can change implementation to allow automatic inference of classes type, you can go with:

```
export function is<T extends any[]>() {
    return <TClasses extends any[]>(...klasses: TClasses) =>
        (...variables: T & { length: TClasses['length'] }) =>
            variables.every((variable, index) => variable instanceof klasses[index]);
}

is<string[]>()(Number, String)('1', '1'); // ok
is<string[]>()(Number, String)(1, 1); // error: not assignable to type 'string[]'
is()(Number, String)(1); // error: Types of property 'length' are incompatible
```

Comment: Ya but I don't want to add two types here; I only want the one type and the other type can be of type `any[]` but of the same length

Comment: @AlekseyL. Your updated solution threw away the type safety for the arguments of the function returned by `is`.

Comment: The issue is, I want the length imposed on the first argument `klasses` not on the second argument. The `T` type is the type for `variables` and I want to make sure `klasses` also has the same length (but not necessarily the same type)

Comment: I updated my answer; that works. If you update your answer, then I can mark it

Comment: @Kousha Unfortunately your update also doesn't work (try `is(Number)(1, 1, 1);`). That's because when wrapper function is resolved `T` is not yet available, so length will be just a `number`. Is you're willing to add extra `()` after `is` - my second example does exactly what you need (you don't need to specify the type of the `klasses` explicitly, it will be inferred automatically)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution using a second type argument for the length. I saw that you don't want another type argument, but I'll add it for completeness sake anyway.

```
export function is<L extends number, T extends any[] & {length: L}>(...klasses: any[] & {length: L}) {
    return (...variables: T) => {
        return variables
            .every((variable, index) => variable instanceof klasses[index]);
    }
}

is(Number, String)(1, 1); // ok
is(Number, String)(1); // error
```

Comment: Elegant solution :) For the examples, `is(Number, String)(1, 1);` compiles but returns false, so the `// ok` is confusing. Perhaps something like `is(Object)({})` ?

Comment: So here if you'd like to specify the type of variables, you'll also need to specify the length, which is not desired I think

Comment: I don't want to provide two templates, just the one `T`; this requires sending both