# Can I define a Typescript generic type as being a tuple of the same length as another tuple?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a function that accepts dataset which is an array of (identically-typed) tuples:

```
type UnknownTuple = any[]
function torgle<T extends UnknownTuple>(list: T[]) {
   ...
}
```

I want to define a second argument that has the same *length* as the tuples, but different types (say, a string label):

```
const records = [
  [7, 'Moo',    true],
  [3, 'Sophie', false],
  [4, 'Tip',    true]
] 
// just an example; dataset is unknown at compile time

torgle(records, ['age', 'name', 'is_fuzzy']) // ok
torgle(records, ['age', 'name'])             // error
```

How can I type the second argument?

```
type UnknownTuple = any[]
function torgle<T extends UnknownTuple>(list: T[], labels: ???) {
   ...
}
```

The question ["Typescript length of a generic type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56034226/typescript-length-of-a-generic-type) is (obviously) very similar, but it has several other things going on (varargs, higher-order functions) that make it difficult to understand the answers, so I think it's worth clarifying things with a simpler example here.

Comment: If the dataset is unknown at compile time, how should you validate the length at compile time?

Comment: @TobiasS. The actual records is unknown but the shape of the tuple may not be -- so I should still be able to typecheck something like `torgle<[number, string, boolean]>(records, labels)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mapped type to transform a tuple into another tuple with the same length as the original:

```
const records = [
  [7, 'Moo',    true] as const, // ensure these are tuples
  [3, 'Sophie', false] as const,
  [4, 'Tip',    true] as const 
]
type UnknownTuple = readonly any[]
type Labels<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: string
}
function torgle<T extends UnknownTuple>(list: T[], labels: Labels<T>) {
   ///...
}
torgle(records, ['age', 'name', 'is_fuzzy']) // ok
torgle(records, ['age', 'name']) // error
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=42&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgU1HAJhGBeGBtAsAKBhwHYAaGAcgFkQQLyiYo4BXBAXRgEN1RIpyAekEwEkFoiYALBBATdJUFgAcANrIJFsAZnIUAyiGVSAlgnowAZl1VzOPGH2ilNOACx6AKieUXGzNntecGgYAnYCKABPZXkAVTAAazAQAHcwTxV1THgELhRwVSjuMCjsCPxo2JgAGS4AIwRbAB5PAD4cgG8CAEhsAAUYEzAYRIQokEsYT3YALhhoOGGAcwIAXwJLFjBgKBNwJhA4ZfVW0QAPKDE0GATktIyshDaAClUTaHnPcvJVBqaIPM6o0Wu0AJQwbqEIjrSJHE4IF6IZBocjYChcZbmPRgLgAW2xlA+AH0tgAvMlRCjsCHCGAgRJw47qJFII6onAYrEWCi4gnU2kiBBwOBHIA)

If you want `torgle` to infer tuple types instead of arrays, you can change the constraint to `[any] | any[]`, but the object literals will need to be specified inline on the call to your function

```
function torgle<T extends [any] | any[]>(list: T[], labels: Labels<T>) {

}
torgle([
  [7, 'Moo', true],
  [3, 'Sophie', false],
  [4, 'Tip', true]
], ['age', 'name', 'is_fuzzy']) // ok
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgazgewO5wCoFcwBtoC8UAThAIYAmycuIUZcIA2gLoCwAUKJFADJkAjCLgDOAHgwA+KEQDenKFCYAFKAEs4UBBBDIAZlAwsAXFBHBiGgOacAvpz1Y4AY2BrqUYMmJX8EqBAAHsAQcBQiSgwgLFAAPvSMrJIAFLhq5qYYrAA0ULiCwiKm-EKiEpIAlFDyHHacXj74yUwKSgDsuQDkALLIyJ25FlgQLNmtTADMXQDKyGAAFmoQA1B6ZKIjYxyKTAAsXRhqYCtDI5yjSp1kVstdcGQAtrdQnekA+o4AXp8gnSxVAHoAVBkAhOPVvL4IM1xh0Xr1+oNiMNRuMpi9Zgslis1htUdslPsXodjkiUedckwrjcVp17k8-oDgRBiMRvEA)

Comment: This looks promising, but in general my records would be coming in from outside and unknown at compile time, so I don't think I can use `const` like this (right?). (Edited question to clarify this.)

Comment: @Sasgorilla You can make its infer tuple for a type parameter, but only if the array literal is passed directly to the function (not stored in another variable) I can add teh change if you're intrested